# Firefox extension - Differences of the chrome and resource protocols?

Tags: firefox-addon

What is the difference between "chrome://", "resource://" and "file://" protocols in Firefox extensions when loading extension scripts? Not related to specific issue, but just want to figure differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `chrome:` is first of all an abstraction, in that all `chrome:` URIs are backed by another URI, such as `file:` or `jar:` ones. The `chrome:` protocol also has some specific protocol flags attached that define certain aspects which are important for security (such as if `http:` is allowed to redirect to `chrome:`, etc.) Lastly, `chrome:` is split into `content`, `skin`, `locale` per registered package name (aggregate of three things), where `skin` and `locale` are special in that they will auto-resolve to the best-match for the current skin and locale (magic). Also some mechanisms explicitly check for the `chrome:` protocol and reject other protocols.
- `resource:` is very similar to `chrome:`, but with less magic (no `skin`/`locale` stuff, ...), just a simple substitution.
- `file:` URIs are just regular file: URIs.

For historic reasons, js code modules are often loaded from `resource:` URIs (and most `resource:` URIs are used to load js code modules), because the module loader used to only support that protocol. Also, restartless add-ons incl. SDK add-ons (internally) made use of `resource:` URIs, because restartless add-ons couldn't even properly register `chrome:` packages until Firefox 8.

However, these days you can also load js code modules from `chrome:` as both the module loader and restartless add-ons support `chrome:` URIs.
So there isn't actually much need to have still use or even have to begin with a `resource:` protocol other than legacy/compatibility reasons.